# bash script: using -e on non-file check

Tags: bash, conditional-statements

I have been learning bash scripting and was trying different things to understand the bash conditionals and put a variable in for a file check.  My understanding is that '-e' checks the existence of a file or directory.

Yes, I know you are not supposed to do var check with file checks, but I was experimenting.
When I read the condition, it looks like 'if $foo exists then echo "yes foo". But was surprised when it was oppposite.

```
foo=true
if [ -e $foo ]
then
  echo "yes foo"
else
  echo "no foo $foo"
fi
```

outputs `no foo true`

My question is why does this happen?

Comment: It happens because there is no file named "true" in your current directory. You want `-n` to check if a variable is set.

Comment: Hummm... you are reading it well. Don't understand why are you surprised. As you said: "'if $foo exists then echo "yes foo"'", but `$foo`==`true`, and `true` does not exist, so you get the `else` clause.

Comment: I understand, So in my example, the 'foo' is much like saying filename. Then end up if exists file with name 'true' and no file exists named 'true'

Comment: BTW, you should double-quote variable references to (e.g. `if [ -e "$foo" ]` instead of just `if [ -e $foo ]`) to avoid parsing problems. For example, if `foo` was not defined or set to the empty string, `if [ -e $foo ]` would expand to `if [ -e ]`, which would evaluate as true because it'd be interpreted as "is '-e' a non-blank string?", and it is! [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at pointing out common mistakes like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the existence of a file with the name true. That file is not there, so the test fails.

If you would for example make your first line foo=/etc/passwd it should (on a unix system) print a "yes foo".